# Why do some male characters in Naruto look like females?

Tags: naruto

Haku looks like a female but is not, also there was one more character but I do not remember the name

Comment: If you haven't watched other anime or read other manga yet, I should let you know that male anime characters looking like females is a common trope in anime and manga. It occurs so often, I daresay it's accepted as normal and no one is surprised about this anymore. These characters are also called 'traps' and the reverse (female looks like male) are 'reverse traps'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common theme throughout a lot of Eastern animation and manga. I suppose depending on where you're from, it might be a little confusing, but in places like Japan, it's a very common theme for male characters to look more feminine, similarly to the concept of a "tomboy", or, a girl who looks or acts more masculine. Often times, and especially in ecchi or hentai animations, these sorts of characters are referred to as "Traps", playing on the theme of being trapped by a person's looks. The easiest way to explain it is by saying that it's just a part of Japanese animation culture. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.